# How to use regex to get last value (4366) , gives - TypeError: location.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor

location =  { height: 52, width: 1360, x: 78.2249984741211, y: 4366 }

var res = location.split(':');

var value = res[4];

Comment: Why not parse the JSON string into a bona-fide object, and then access the `y` key?

Comment: Tim has the right idea. JSON.parse( "{ \"height\": 52, \"width\": 1360, \"x\": 78.2249984741211, \"y\": 4366 }")

Comment: what data type is your location? object or a string?

Answer (score 2):

split works on strings, not objects.
**example:**

```
 'mystring:value'.split(':')
```

**You don't need split here. Just do**

```
result = location.y
```